# C# numeric onscreen keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-8.1, numeric-input

I'm developing app for tablet with Win 8.1. I've got some TextBoxes with numeric input only and I need to popup numeric onscreen keyboard instead of standard one when entered.
There's InputScope for WinPhone. Exists anything similar for Win 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is property `InputScope="Number"` in Win 8.1 TextBox too.

Comment: Finally found it, it's for System.Windows.Controls.TextBox. Any idea of convert System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to System.Windows.Controls.TextBox? I've got them placed them to right position by Visual Studio

Comment: What is you project type Windows Store App or Windows Form Application, because in windows store app you have Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox and Windows store app is project type for windows 8.1 tablet application.

Comment: Windows Form App. The sponsor has been against xaml.

Comment: So basically it will be a standard applications which will not be downloading from store. If you aiming tablet application you should consider use Windows Store Application. About InputScope i think you cannot achieve this thing. But you can check user input to be only numeric symbols.

Comment: Yeah, input is numeric only already.
What about adding wpf component to the form and use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox there?

Comment: You can  try but on my Simulator your suggestion isnt working i dont have a real device to test it right now. But there is InputScope which accept Number type if you have real device you can try.